# Generate Image Zend speed up

Tags: php, image, zend-framework

I use Zend, and I use a Controller to create dynamicly images.
But it slows my whole page down, cause, for every picture, the controller loads the Zend Library.

Is there a way to use Zend Functions, but not the whole Zend Lib for this controller?

Comment: ZF libraries are normally loaded on demand, so that's probably already happening. Serving images with PHP is always slower than serving them directly; and generating images on the fly is always slower than serving static images. I'd suggest you benchmark to see where the bottlenecks are. If you add some code to your question that might help too.

Comment: When I load an empty controller without any code it allready takes about 150ms.